# ¿Cómo usar los atributos de una clase hija en un array de la clase padre?

Tags: c++

Supongamos tengo el siguiente código:

```
class Producto{};

class Fruta: public Producto{

 public:

 string calidad = "buena";

};

class Verdura: public Producto{};
```

Y quiero un array que pueda tener elementos de fruta y verdura a la vez. Para esto, podría crear un array de la clase padre `Producto` que contiene a ambos:

```
Producto* productos[100];
```

Y supongamos escojo que el producto con índice cero sea una fruta, esto es:

```
productos[0] = new Fruta();
```

Debido a que `productos` lo declaré como un array de la clase  `Producto` y sin embargo estoy asignándole una clase Hija, entonces(por lo que sé) C++ casteará `new Fruta()` a `Producto`. Y aquí viene mi problema ya que me gustaría acceder a los atributos de `Fruta` del modo `productos[0] -> calidad` sin embargo no pude.

Intenté castearlo con `static_cast<Fruta*>(productos[0])` es decir transformarlo a un objeto de la clase `Fruta`(por lo que sé, esto es lo que hace) sin embargo esto tampoco me sirvió porque si bien pude acceder al atributo, no quiero usar `static_cast<Fruta*>(productos[0])` cada vez que tenga que acceder a algún atributo o método de esta. Intenté hacer `productos[0] = static_cast<Fruta*>(productos[0])`, es decir, intentar que `productos[0]` apuntará a su "forma casteada" sin embargo no surge efecto alguno.

Answer (score 2):

> no quiero usar static_cast<Fruta*>(productos[0])

Pues lamento ser yo quien te lo diga, pero esa es la forma de hacerlo. De alguna u otra forma, tienes que *moldear* el puntero, desde *puntero a clase base* hasta *puntero a clase hija*.

> intentar que productos[0] apuntará a su "forma casteada" sin embargo no surge efecto alguno.

Eso es **imposible**. El tipo queda fijado **a fuego** en el momento de declarar la variable. Si es `Producto* productos[100]`, el compilador lo tiene **muy en cuenta** en el código y no te dejará tratar ningún elemento de forma distinta a lo que es, un *puntero a Producto*.

> no quiero usar static_cast<Fruta*>(productos[0]) cada vez

Siempre puedes usar una variable auxiliar para minimizar eso ... aunque siempre tendrás que hacerlo por lo menos 1 vez:

```
Fruta &fruta = *static_cast< Fruta * >( productos[0] );

fruta.calidad = "Malísima";
```

#### Alternativa 1

Puedes *ocultar* la variable-miembro `calidad` dentro de una función-miembro (un *getter*, vamos), y hacerlo `virtual`, declarándolo en la clase base `Producto`:

```
class Producto {
public:
    virtual const std::string &calidad( ) const = 0;
    virtual std::string &calidad( ) const = 0;
    virtual void setCalidad( std::string ) = 0;
};

class Fruta : public Producto {
public:
    const std::string &calidad( ) const override;
    std::string &calidad( ) override;
    void setCalidad( std::string ) override;

private:
    std::string m_calidad;
};
```

Esta posibilidad puede o no ser aplicable en tu caso. Desde luego, es la mas cómoda.

**Esto no es gratis**. Las clases con miembros virtuales dejan de ser conformes con [`StandardLayoutType`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/StandardLayoutType), y puede o no tener implicaciones en tu código. No obstante, sigue siendo **con mucha diferencia** lo más cómodo y fácil de usar.

Aquí existen variaciones para no incumplir `StandardLayoutType`, como usar variables-miembro de tipo *puntero a función*; pero complican **mucho** el código, al perder la *complicidad*  del compilador: el mantenimiento de esos punteros a funciones corre de nuestra parte; ese tema queda ya fuera del ámbito de la pregunta.

#### Alternativa 2

Puedes usar una [`union`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union):

```
union UnionDeProductos {
    UnionDeProductos( ) : producto( nullptr ) { }
    Producto *producto;
    Fruta *fruta;
    Verdura *verdura;
};

UnionDeProductos productos[100];
```

Esto proporciona una especie de *casteo automágico* entre todas los tipos implicados, de forma que puedes hacer

```
auto calidad = productos[0].fruta.calidad;
```

El problema es que **es tu responsabilidad** saber a que tipo corresponde realmente cada elemento. Es un punto diametralmente opuesto al de origen. El compilador te obligaba a hacer *cast* antes de usar, y ahora el *cast* es automático **siempre** y eres tú el que tiene que comprobar que está bien hecho :-)

Normalmente, se usa un valor *extra* para indicar el tipo real que se está usando:

```
enum TipoDeProducto {
    Error,
    TipoFruta,
    TipoVerdura
};

struct ProductoGenerico {
    ProductoGenerico( ) : tipo( TipoDeProducto::Error ) { }
    int tipo;
    union {
        Producto *producto;
        Fruta *fruta;
        Verdura *verdura;
    };
};

switch( productos[0].tipo ) {
case TipoDeProducto::TipoFruta:
    productos[0].fruta->calidad = "Que feo";
    break;

case TipoDeProducto::TipoVerdura:
    productos[0].verdura-> ...

default:
    // Si llegamos aquí, no tiene valor asignado.
}
```

#### Alternativa 3

Usa la nueva clase [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) de C++17:

```
std::any productos[100];

try {
    std::any_cast< Fruta >( productos[0] ).calidad = "Regular";
} catch( const std::bad_any_cast& e ) {
    std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
}
```

Como ves, no es que exista mucha diferencia sobre usar *cast* manuales. Pero al menos te libera de comprobaciones extra.